# Can I use cookies to run code after the jsTree tree loads and its status is restored?

Tags: jquery, jstree

How can I run a block of code in jsTree after the tree has finished loading **and** has been restored to its previous state? (I’m using the cookie plugin.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems I got a functional work-around...

By binding to the the `select_node` event and not the `open_node` event, you can perform your operation only after the final node is opened; this is because only the previously selected node (before the browser refresh) becomes selected after the tree is fully reloaded.

Here is the binding code. Try it out and you will see what I mean:

```
    .bind("open_node.jstree", function(e, data){
        console.log('tree opened node ' + data.rslt.obj.attr("url"));

        var selectedNode = $('#tree').jstree("get_selected");

        if(selectedNode != null)
        {
            console.log(selectedNode.attr('id'));
        }
    })
    .bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
        var a = $.jstree._focused().get_selected();

        console.log('tree selected node ' + data.rslt.obj.attr("url"));

        var selectedNode = $('#tree').jstree("get_selected");

        if(selectedNode != null)
        {
            console.log(selectedNode.attr('id'));
        }
    })
```